# Setting up an ftp server on OSx server edition

Tags: macos, installation

Can anyone direct me to a link that explains how to setup an ftp server on OSx server edition?  I searched for awhile and didn't find anything very useful.

Comment: Think you should move this question to serverfault.com

Comment: Okay didn't know about serverfault thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

OS X Server has FTP built-in. You configure FTP serving of share points along with other protocols from the File Sharing Tab UI in Server Admin (click on a share point, then "Protocol Options..." in the bottom pane).

Answer (score 1):

The question is "Can anyone direct me to a link that explains how to setup an ftp server on OSX server edition?"
Here you go:
http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/File_Server_Admin_v10.6.pdf

Other good stuff here:
http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/resources/documentation.html